# No software update on my iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone

Why doesn't my iPhone 4s have any iOS software updates available? How can I update this phone some other way?

Answer (score 6):

The latest version of iOS, version 10, does not run on any iPhone earlier than the iPhone 5.

For your iPhone 4s the latest version that will run is iOS 9.3.5

Answer (score 0):

The only way to continue support is to jailbreak.

http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/08/10/jailbreak-ios-935-phoenix-move-from-version-1/

I do not support piracy or anything else that is capable through jailbreak. However, jailbreaking will give you the ability to continue to get some kind of support for your device. You will at least have additional options and another place to download Apps when apple makes it so that you can't download apps anymore. You will lose your warranty but I'm pretty sure it's expired by now anyway.